# How to get the current App name in models.py in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.4

I have a app called C3po. I'm working on the model "Article". In this model I want to create a ForeignKey field with a custom related_name to a model in another app called Lea. To make sure the related_name is unique, I want to name it "c3po_articles". But I don't want to hard code the app name c3po. How can I get the folder / app name in a dynamic way ? Do I use __file__ and split it or is there a more elegant method ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You can use model.app_name, but the relation name should be probably used in your code, so I can't see why this dynamic way will be flexible enough...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand completely. Shouldn't I do it this way ? I just want to be able to rename the model later without editing the whole code.

Comment: related_name is used for loading the values from the relation - e.g. if related_name="articles", then you use myobj.articles.all() to load all articles that are available for myobj. I don't see a way to rename the related_name without editing the code that uses that relation? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The `related_name` attribute supports automatic string interpolation with two variables: `app_label` and `class`. For example:

```
models.ForeignKey(FooModel, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_foo')
```

Now, I'm honestly not sure if Django will let you just include one or the other, i.e. just `'%(app_label)s_foo'`, but you can try. (After a closer look at the docs, I highly doubt it. It seems like it's both or neither, but still, test it yourself and see.)

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

**EDIT**

Actually, after thinking about it more, for your case, you could just use `'%(app_label)s_%(class)ss'`, which should net you `c3po_articles` as the `related_name`.